# Blackberry - how to resize image?

Tags: graphics, blackberry, drawing, custom-controls, image-scaling

I wanted to know if we can resize an image. Suppose if we want to draw an image of 200x200 actual size with a size of 100 x 100 size on our blackberry screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just an alternative:
[BlackBerry - draw image on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426299/blackberry-draw-image-on-the-screen)
[BlackBerry - image 3D transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212651/blackberry-image-3d-transform)

Answer (score 10):

You can do this pretty simply using the [`EncodedImage.scaleImage32()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EncodedImage.html#scaleImage32%28int,%20int%29) method. You'll need to provide it with the factors by which you want to scale the width and height (as a [`Fixed32`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/math/Fixed32.html)).

Here's some sample code which determines the scale factor for the width and height by dividing the original image size by the desired size, using RIM's [`Fixed32`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/math/Fixed32.html) class.

```
public static EncodedImage resizeImage(EncodedImage image, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    int scaleFactorX = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(image.getWidth()), Fixed32.toFP(newWidth));
    int scaleFactorY = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(image.getHeight()), Fixed32.toFP(newHeight));
    return image.scaleImage32(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
}
```

If you're lucky enough to be developer for OS 5.0, Marc posted a link to the [new APIs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#scaleInto%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap,%20int%29) that are a lot clearer and more versatile than the one I described above. For example:

```
public static Bitmap resizeImage(Bitmap originalImage, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
    originalImage.scaleInto(newImage, Bitmap.FILTER_BILINEAR, Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FILL);
    return newImage;
}
```

(Naturally you can substitute the filter/scaling options based on your needs.)

Comment: @TreeUK: I have that exact function in working code right now. Are you converting the `int`s to `Fixed32` and using `Fixed32.div()` to figure out the scale factors? Normal integer division won't cut it.

Comment: Thanks, was using it incorrectly. Not integer related, but still wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a Blackberry programmer, but I believe some of these links will help you out:

[Image Resizing Article](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Image-Resize/m-p/25838)
[Resizing a Bitmap on the Blackberry](http://www.coderholic.com/resizing-a-bitmap-on-the-blackberry/)
[Blackberry Image Scaling Question](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/25597-resizing-image.html)

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that the default image scaling done by BlackBerry is quite primitive and generally doesn't look very good.  If you are building for 5.0 there is a [new API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#scaleInto%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap,%20int%29) to do much better image scaling using filters such as bilinear or Lanczos.

Answer (score 2):

For BlackBerry JDE 5.0 or later, you can use the [scaleInto](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#scaleInto%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap,%20int%29) API.

Answer (score 1):

```
in this there is two bitmap.temp is holding the old bitmap.In this method you just pass
bitmap ,width,height.it return new bitmap of your choice.

  Bitmap ImgResizer(Bitmap bitmap , int width , int height){
    Bitmap temp=new Bitmap(width,height);
    Bitmap resized_Bitmap = bitmap;
    temp.createAlpha(Bitmap.HOURGLASS);
    resized_Bitmap.scaleInto(temp , Bitmap.FILTER_LANCZOS);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: just call this method  and hold this in to a bitmap..enjoy

Comment: scaleInto() for Bitmap is available since OS 5.0.

Comment: @Lucas Yes it has been since  BlackBerry API 5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function or you can say method to resize image, use it as you want :

```
int olddWidth;
int olddHeight;
int dispplayWidth;
int dispplayHeight;

EncodedImage ei2 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("add2.png");
olddWidth = ei2.getWidth();
olddHeight = ei2.getHeight();
dispplayWidth = 40;\\here pass the width u want in pixels
dispplayHeight = 80;\\here pass the height u want in pixels again

int numeerator = net.rim.device.api.math.Fixed32.toFP(olddWidth);
int denoominator = net.rim.device.api.math.Fixed32.toFP(dispplayWidth);
int widtthScale = net.rim.device.api.math.Fixed32.div(numeerator, denoominator);
numeerator = net.rim.device.api.math.Fixed32.toFP(olddHeight);
denoominator = net.rim.device.api.math.Fixed32.toFP(dispplayHeight);
int heighhtScale = net.rim.device.api.math.Fixed32.div(numeerator, denoominator);
EncodedImage newEi2 = ei2.scaleImage32(widtthScale, heighhtScale); 
Bitmap _add =newEi2.getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answers for newbie in Blackberry Application development. Below code is for processing Bitmap images from URL and Resizing them without loass of Aspect Ratio :

```
   public static Bitmap imageFromServer(String url)
{
Bitmap bitmp = null;
try{
HttpConnection fcon = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
int rc = fcon.getResponseCode();
if(rc!=HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
{
    throw new IOException("Http Response Code : " + rc);            
}
InputStream httpInput = fcon.openDataInputStream();
InputStream inp = httpInput;
byte[] b = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(inp);
EncodedImage img = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(b, 0, b.length);
bitmp = resizeImage(img.getBitmap(), 100, 100);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
Dialog.alert("Exception : " + e.getMessage());          
}
return bitmp;
}

public static Bitmap resizeImage(Bitmap originalImg, int newWidth, int newHeight)
{
    Bitmap scaledImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
    originalImg.scaleInto(scaledImage, Bitmap.FILTER_BILINEAR, Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FIT);
    return scaledImage;
}
```

The Method resizeImage is called inside the method imageFromServer(String url).
1) the image from server is processed using EncodedImage img.
2) Bitmap bitmp = resizeImage(img.getBitmap(), 100, 100);
parameters are passed to resizeImage() and the return value from resizeImage() is set to Bitmap bitmp.