# Do Bitmap.scaleInto() function will work on older version of blackberry actual device

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm, blackberry-jde

Can anyone tell me that do scaleinto function  will work on actual device having older os that 5.0. Bleow is the code.

```
 public static Bitmap resizeImage(Bitmap originalImage, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
   Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
   originalImage.scaleInto(newImage, Bitmap.FILTER_BILINEAR, Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FILL);
  return newImage;
 }
```

Comment: You can take a look at my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769755/blackberry-how-to-resize-image/2268027#2268027) for a way of resizing images that will work on older devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can see in the [API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#scaleInto%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) that the scaleInto method was only added in OS 5.0.  You will not be able to use it on older devices.