# Increase the height widht of image as per BB screen size

Tags: image, blackberry, image-processing

I have written the following code to add image as a background to the BlackBerry screen.The image size is 320*240.The image is added to the screen but then I want to increase its height and width according to the size of the BB screen height and width.

Following is the code I have written:

```
Bitmap xtclogoBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("launch_xtc.jpg");
BitmapField xtcbitmapField = new BitmapField(xtclogoBitmap,Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
add(xtcbitmapField);
```

How can I increase the height and width of the image as per the BB screen size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blackberry - how to resize image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769755/blackberry-how-to-resize-image)

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap img=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("3.jpg");
Bitmap bg = new Bitmap(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
img.scaleInto(bg,Bitmap.FILTER_LANCZOS, Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FILL);
```

you can replace Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FILL and/or modify the values of getheight and width by addition for example depending on your needs, then just add the bg

check this explanation from BlackBerry [here](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#FILTER_LANCZOS)

regards,