# Blackberry - set field background image stetched to fit

Tags: blackberry

How can you scale an image - whether it be using Bitmap or EncodedImage to fill the entire width and height of a field?

Tried this:

```
protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
    super.paintBackground(g);
     //try bitmap
     //g.drawBitmap(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), image 0, 0);
     //try encoded image
     g.drawImage(0, 0, this.getContentWidth(), this.getContentHeight(), image, 0, 0, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This questn is asked before here is link [Blackberry - how to resize image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769755/blackberry-how-to-resize-image)

In OS 5.0 the api scaleInto method is provided in Bitmap class i.e 
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#scaleInto%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap,%20int%29

For Below OS 5.0 this bb kb article will be helpful for image manipulations
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Rotate-and-scale-bitmaps/ta-p/492524

Comment: Thanks, I'm targeting devices a old as 4.5.  I have the encodedimage resizing function you mention elsewhere is my code - my problem is more in passing the width/height to these functions.  getWidth() and getHeight() of these field seem to be outputting some large integers that throw errors when passed to the resizing functions.