# Set width and height on BlackBerry BitmapField

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How do I set width and height of a BitmapField in BlackBerry? The following code works, but I can't show the entire image. The display shows only some portion of my image.

```java
 BitmapField bmp = new BitmapField(connectServerForImage(ImageUrl)) {
       protected void layout(int width, int height) 
       {
          setExtent(80, 70);
       }
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're saying that your `BitmapField` is showing the image you retrieve **cropped**?

And you would like it to scale, perhaps scaled to fit the size of your `BitmapField`?  There's many ways to do that, but one is to resize the image after downloading, before giving it to the `BitmapField`:

[From this answer on resizing a Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2268027/119114)

```java
public static Bitmap resizeImage(Bitmap originalImage, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
    originalImage.scaleInto(newImage, Bitmap.FILTER_BILINEAR, Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FILL);
    return newImage;
}
```

(Note that the link I provided has an alternate method for resizing images, if you have to support BlackBerry OS < 5.0).

Then, use

```java
Bitmap img = resizeImage(connectServerForImage(ImageUrl), 80, 70);
BitmapField bmp = new BitmapField(img) {
       protected void layout(int width, int height) 
       {
          setExtent(80, 70);
       }
};
```

However, I believe that if you actually set the size of the `Bitmap` `img` to 80x70, then there's no need to **also** set the extent of the `BitmapField` to 80x70.  It should default to the size of the image you give it.  So, you could simplify the code to:

```java
BitmapField bmp = new BitmapField(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int prefWidth=(30*bitmap.getWidth())/bitmap.getHeight();
 Bitmap temp=resizeBitmap(bitmap,prefWidth,30);
```

where

```
 private Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap image, int width, int height)
{   

    int rgb[] = new int[image.getWidth()*image.getHeight()];
    image.getARGB(rgb, 0, image.getWidth(), 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    int rgb2[] = rescaleArray(rgb, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), width, height);
    Bitmap temp2 = new Bitmap(width, height);
    temp2.setARGB(rgb2, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return temp2;
}
```

This support bb os 4.5