# How do I scale down my image to be half the size with scaleImage32()?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, bitmap, image-resizing

Right now I have:

```
    EncodedImage logo = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("image.png");
    logo.scaleImage32(Fixed32.toFP(2), Fixed32.toFP(2));
    BitmapField image = new BitmapField(logo.getBitmap());
    image.setMargin(15, 15, 15, 15);
    this.add(image);
```

and it just displays the image at its normal size.  However, `logo.setScale(2)` works instead of `.scaleImage32(...)`, but it's deprecated.

What is the correct way to use .scaleImage32() to display my image half the size it is?

Comment: Though you are correct, when I say 'half the size' I am talking about its dimensions, not its area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you've been snookered by a crummy API, and in my opinion, a weakness of Java (and all the C languages).

You thought that `scaleImage32()` was scaling your `logo` image.  It wasn't.  It was returning a copy of `logo` that was scaled.  You, however, didn't do anything with this value.  You used `logo` for display in your bitmap field, when you really needed the scaled copy that `scaleImage32()` returns:

```
EncodedImage logo = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("image.png");
EncodedImage scaledLogo = logo.scaleImage32(Fixed32.toFP(2), Fixed32.toFP(2));
BitmapField image = new BitmapField(scaledLogo.getBitmap());
```

I will add a few things:

1) if you can restrict your app to OS 5.0 and above, I [think that the scaleInto() API is easier to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2268027/119114)

2) this kind of scenario is why people fuss over method names.  RIM picked a poor name for `scaleImage32()`, as that leads you to believe that the instance on which you call the method will be scaled.  It should have been named `getScaledImage32()`, or something like that.

3) under the heading of *obscure programming stuff that I'm embarrased to admit*, I used to code in [Ada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_(programming_language)).  Ada was geared towards doing as much as possible to prevent programming errors.  One thing Ada featured was that the compiler treats an unused return value as an error.  This scenario is exactly why.

So, don't feel too bad about this one :)